# How to explode multiple columns that contain a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining

I have a dataset that includes different types of tags. Each column has a string that contains a list of tags.
How am I supposed to explode selected columns at the same time ?

```
  Unnamed: id    Tag1     Tag2
0          A     a,b,c    d,e
1          B     m,n      x
```

to this:

```
Unnamed: id    Tag1     Tag2
0          A     a      d
1          A     a      e
2          A     b      d
3          A     b      e
4          A     c      d
6          A     c      e
7          B     m      x
8          B     n      x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split the string values of each `Tag` column into lists, using `Series.apply` + `Series.str.split`. I'm using `DataFrame.filter` to select only the columns which starts with `'Tag'`.

Then, use `DataFrame.explode` in a loop to explode sequentially each `Tag` column of the `df`, turning the values of each list into new rows.

```
tag_cols = df.filter(like='Tag').columns
df[tag_cols] = df[tag_cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.split(','))

for col in tag_cols:
    df = df.explode(col, ignore_index=True)
    
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  id Tag1 Tag2
0  A    a    d
1  A    a    e
2  A    b    d
3  A    b    e
4  A    c    d
5  A    c    e
6  B    m    x
7  B    n    x
```

Note that using just `df.apply(lambda col: col.str.split(',').explode())` won't work in this case because some rows have strings/lists with a different number of elements. Therefore the rows can't be correctly aligned after exploding them, and `apply` will complain.

Comment: @Sky does my answer solve your problem?